# From WordPress Custom Post Type to Chartjs

Tags: wordpress, chart.js

I would to pass the chartjs data as a custom post type, I mean, I've created a custom post type with 2 custom fields, data_x and data_y and I would like to take those data and pass them to a chart using chartjs.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. What did you tried so far and what is exactly your issue?

Comment: I think I have to pass the data from a custom query to an array and after that encode the array to json object, but I don't know how to call that object in javascript, maybe with ajax but I don't know how to it, if I could see some example would be great.

Comment: You could just echo the json string in a `<string>` tag on your template with something like that: `<script>var json_results = '<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>';</script>`

Comment: mmm...but the json string es in a php file and the script is a js file. How can I use php in the js file?

Comment: Your template file is a php file. So if you echo your string inside a script tag, then the js var will be ready to use on the page load.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally I got it